# GAE DataStore : Any example of using executeWithArray

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to apply more than three filter criteria on Query.  I came to know that this is possible using executeWithArray. Can someone share example of it? I need to apply more than three filters involving different columns.

Comment: Hi, I suspect you'll get better responses if you should switch your question to 'GAE DataStore:...".

Comment: Which language: Java or Python? You should tag the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to apply more than three filter in query if I make filter string using the direct criteria:

Example: I added `isClosed=='N'` criteria directly in the filter string.

```
query.setFilter("trackerId == trackerParam && projectId == projParam && 
    codeListIds.contains(filId) && isClosed=='N'");
```

Still, Query can max three parameters only:

```
query.declareParameters("Long trackerParam,Long projParam,Long filId");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java. There are a lot of examples on the [Queries and Indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html) page, and it explains the restrictions involving the different filters (under "Restrictions on Queries"). A quick summary:

- Most likely, the issue is that you can only have an inequality filter on one column. You can do an "=" filter on as many columns as you like, but you can only do "!=", "<", "<=", ">" or ">=" on a single column in one query.
- If you have an inequality filter, and are also sorting the output, you need to sort first on the column used in the inequality filter.
- If you are using transactions, all queries must be "ancestor queries" -- you must restrict the query to only entities with a certain parent.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have seen the link and could not find answer to my question. i do not have any inequality criteria , i just have all equal criteria but i have more than three, four.

Comment: Well, do you have an actual problem? Because you haven't said if it isn't working; you haven't asked any question at all. What exactly are you trying to do, and what is going wrong?